# Which SCM and Issue tracker for personal work?

Tags: version-control, issue-tracking

I am planning to bring some "peace" (you may call it organization) to the personal work (small projects, etc.) I do at home.

I would like to use a `SCM` and an `issue tracker` which can capture the commits and show them as changesets etc. automatically.

**Note** that all the above applications are supposed to be for personal usage so would prefer something from `FOSS` and also they need to be ultra lightweight in terms of the system requirements.

What do you recommend?

**EDIT:**  Following are some of my doubts/concerns:

1. `Git` with `GitHub` looks good. But I am not very comfortable with making my code base public on `GitHub`. What do you say?
2. Does `GitHub` provide an issue tracker? I mean, can I open up an issue on `GitHub` provided issue tracker and commit against that issue?
3. Can I have a local `SCM` (on my laptop) and use some `remote issue tracker` like [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/StudentAndStartup.html)? But I just don't understand how could a remote issue tracker capture my commits. Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

I finally went with `Mercurial` and [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org). Working awesome so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [Git](http://git-scm.com/) with [GitHub](http://github.com/)

Comment: I'm not sure that GitHub provides an integrated issue tracker. Do you use any issue trackers that integrate well with Git?

Comment: Does have an issue tracker now.

Answer (score 3):

I like and use [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) with the [basecamp theme](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/ThemeBasecamp). It supports a couple of version control systems like git, mercurial, svn, ...

For projects that I want to publish I use [bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org) and [github.com](http://github.com).

I never tried, but would look into git in combination with [ticgit](http://wiki.github.com/schacon/ticgit) ..

Answer (score 2):

If you're going free personal, I'd recommend [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/).  The two integrate very well together with a little bit of configuration.  They're also both pretty lightweight.

If you're willing to spend a bit or are working on an open source project, I'd recommend [Atlassian's](http://www.atlassian.com/) tools Jira and FishEye.  I've worked with them as well and have found integration to be very good.  They can be a bit hefty though, and I've found the FishEye client to be very AJAX heavy to the point of performance issues.

Comment: Non-distributedd source control, you would miss soo, soo much.  Better to start distributed.

Answer (score 1):

If you can trust that you'll always be working on your personal projects near your source control server (or if you're doing it all on the same box) then I'd suggest Subversion.  I feel the barrier for entry is lower for it than distributed tools like git or mercurial.

I'd look into [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) for your server.
If you're running it all on one box, you can use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)'s built-in Repo feature.

My favorite clients are [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) (if you need VS integration.)

For an issue tracker, [a simple story board](http://www.secretgeek.net/desk_story_wall.asp) might be better than a piece of software.

Comment: The difference between developing agile-ly in a distributed source control and on svn are like night and day, so -1 for non-distributed svn.  As an alternative, I suggest at least starting off trying mercurial and tortoiseHg instead.

Comment: @Tchalvak - That is a weighty opinion, and one you're quite entitled to: no problems there but I feel you're missing the intent of the voting system by down voting answers which you disagree with when there is nothing factually inaccurate in the post.  Furthermore, I address your distributed SCM point head on by suggesting the lower entry barrier may be desirable in this "small scale" environment.

Answer (score 1):

I use [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) in emacs to track personal projects.

I've used various SCMs for personal work. For really small stuff I still sometimes just run `ci -l somefile` to start versioning with [RCS](http://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/), because I'm old-school that way. I've happily used [Darcs](http://darcs.net/) for personal stuff, and I maintain that Darcs is *still* the easiest to use DVCS out there. These days if I think I'm going to be Open-Sourcing the project I'm likely to use Git, just because that makes putting it on GitHub straightforward.

I also like to use personal projects as an opportunity to experiment with other SCMs that I'm not familiar with, so I'll probably be versioning projects with [Bazaar](http://bazaar-vcs.org/en/) and [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used CVS for source control, but I've recently started converting most of my personal projects to use [git](http://git-scm.com/).  However, I don't like the way git works with Visual Studio, so I've been switching to [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) for my C# projects.

For issue tracking, I've been using [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) which supports all three SCM methods, though it does better with SVN and git.

Answer (score 0):

Lightweight issue tracking, well, you could use the tracker in drupal, if you consider LAMP easy enough to set up.

If you want to be self-contained, git and mercurial are things you can use without setting up a server at all.

Of course, there's good-old-RCS.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to second using the Subversion and Trac combination. I have this environment setup at work and use it for a distributed team of developers, and I have this environment setup at home and use it for my personal projects. They are open source, very adaptable to your workflow and [Trac Hacks](http://trac-hacks.org/) has pretty much any mod / hack / plugin you could think of in one form or another.

Comment: As a follow up to this comment (2 years later) I now use Git and Subversion with Redmine, and have migrated my Trac environments over. Redmine has infinitely better multi-project support, and it's support for multiple SCM's is perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

For very personal things (let's say single-user-mode) I use Tomboy (a simple note-taking application) and Getting Things Gnome. If the project becomes more complex, then I used to switch to Trac with svn or hg backend. For next projects, I'm going to try redmine: seems more clean and hipe than trac (:))